# What is the fastest Area 51 proposal to reach the Beta stage?

Tags: discussion, area-51, statistics, beta-phase

The site proposal [Proof Assistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) has gone from Definition to completing Commitment in just over three days. Has any proposal (whether it managed through Beta or not) achieved this in a shorter duration?

Comment: What is the story behind this? This must have been organised outside Stack Exchange (especially when it is so narrow and specialised as this). Who, how, where, when, and what?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q my guess is group of people using social platform to communicate, e.g. Facebook group, WhatsApp, etc, and acting together to achieve their goal. That's the only way to have a proposed site reach Beta in these days.

Comment: It'll take some time to reach beta. Typically, beta launches are approved on Thursdays with the actual launch taking place on the following Monday or Tuesday, but this Thursday is a holiday here in the U.S. (Thanksgiving day).  As such, it likely won't be launched until at least December 6.

Comment: [This Tweet mentioning the proposal](https://twitter.com/andrejbauer/status/1461809941778419716) got quite a bit of attention.

Answer (score -1):

How about a programmatic solution?

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms || DEF_DELAY));
}
async function getMinimumTime() {
  var proposal = 1;
  var done = false;
  var minimumTime = Infinity;
  var minimumPost = null;
  while(!done) {
    await $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: `https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/${proposal}?phase=commitment`,
      success: function(proposalRawBody) {
        var proposalBody = $("<html>").html(proposalRawBody);
        if(proposalBody.find(".phase-name").text() != "Definition") {
          var proposedDate = new Date(proposalBody.find('.label-key:contains("proposed by")').parent().find(".label-value:first > span").attr("title"));
          var committmentStartDate = new Date(proposalBody.find('.label-key:contains("first commit")').nextAll().filter(".label-value:first").find("span").attr("title"));
          var timeBeforeCommitment = committmentStartDate - proposedDate;
          if(!Object.is(timeBeforeCommitment, NaN) && timeBeforeCommitment < minimumTime) {
            minimumTime = timeBeforeCommitment;
            minimumPost = proposal;
          }
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        done = true;
      },
      ajax: false
    });
    ++proposal;
    await sleep(500);
  }
  return minimumPost;
}
```

Go to any area 51 page, paste this in the developer console and wait about 10 hours while it searches every proposal for the smallest time between the proposal and the first commit.  I'll edit in the results when it finishes running.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this post?

Comment: You seem to be measuring the fastest a proposal went through the definition phase. The commitment phase is a second step _before_ the private beta begins. The question is asking for the quickest proposal to reach Beta, not to reach Commitment. And while a "private beta start" date is available on the beta tab, this can be trickier to gauge given that there can sometimes between 1-3 weeks between commitment reaching 100% and a proposal actually going into beta due to various factors in company planning. E.g. this particular proposal is _not_ private beta yet, as they are still waiting.

Comment: @animuson Should this measure the end of the commitment phase, then?